# Install multiple version of node.js using NVM (Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, installation, nvm

How to install multiple version of node.js in Ubuntu using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## prior knowledge

How to use the terminal. You can for example use `gnome-terminal`.

## Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core
```

## Install NVM

Below we will install NVM.

### Download nvm

```
git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

### To activate nvm, you need to source it from your bash shell

```
echo -e "\n. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Install version of node.js

In this example, I am going to install node v0.4.12. We first need open new bash session. You can also do this by typing `bash` again.

```
$ bash
$ nvm install v0.4.12 #This takes a while.
```

To make the latest v0.4 branch default you do

```
$ nvm alias default 0.4
```

## Troubleshooting

When you don't have all dependencies installed you can not compile/install node.js. Then you will need to clean up ~/.nvm

```
$ rm -rf ~/.nvm/
```

Comment: That echo line caused me some issues on Ubuntu 12.04. Had to edit the file and change it to `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a detailed, up-to-date manual: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps#installation

Comment: The article is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

The top answer is out of date. Now, just follow the guide on the github to install :

https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

For linux machines, its as simple as :

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v*/install.sh | bash`

Replace `v*` with the latest version from https://github.com/creationix/nvm/releases.

For example:
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`

Answer (score 0):

## Install Node.js with Node Version Manager in linux (Ubuntu, linux mint)

---

### 1. Build essential package

> sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall

### 2. Get libssl-dev

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

### 3. Install nvm using cURL

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cre... | bash

### 4. Check installation work

> command -v nvm

### 5. List available node versions

> nvm ls-remote

### 6. download, compile and install node

> nvm install 6.14.4

### 7. Tell nvm which version to use

> nvm use 6.14.4

### 8. Set default node version

> nvm alias default node 6.14.4

[More Info](https://youtu.be/3b5cpGJ7hGw?t=228)