# Error during install node js in debian

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I trying to install in `debian nodejs`, I am following these steps [how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04) but when I run `sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh` the errors below showed for me, anyone help me to solve it ?

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu maverick Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Falhou ao buscar http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Falhou ao buscar http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to NodeJS's package in any way.

The real issue is stated:

> The repository basically_all_your_repos does not have a Release file.

Your ppa entries are corrupted. Delete all ppa entries which throw errors and then run `apt-get update`. I'm guessing the installation fails at the beginning, when *(sudo) apt-get update* is issued. You can check out how to remove *ppa*s [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **NVM** to install node js and it helps to checkout different node versions in the same machine for different project.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791682/4322261). I clearly listed the commands on how to install node js with NVM on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using Software & Updates Application
From https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253291/11032592

1. Open the Software Updates application;
2. In "Other Software" tab unmark all options;
3. In Ubuntu Software tab, "Download from:" choose "Main server" option.
4. Click in "Close" button and wait a minute until ubuntu reload apt-get.
5. Open terminal --> sudo apt-get clean all
6. Open terminal --> sudo apt-get update
   Done.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know the EXACT name of the "Software Updates" application? When I go into the configuration settings for "update", I always get into the full Windows update. When I go to "app" configuration I don't find any update related things (I'm working on Windows-10 and I have installed Ubuntu (Windows Linux subsystem) as an app).

Comment: Im not familiar with your setup, but in my Ubuntu distro I find it by searching in the menu bar, just start typing "Software..." and the application will appear.